# Load div using Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 5 div on one page. Something like that:

```
<div id="div1"> some content </div>
<div id="div2"> some content </div>
<div id="div3"> some content </div>
<div id="div4"> some content </div>
<div id="div5"> some content </div>
<button> Load More </button>
```

I want to make only first div loaded, after clicks button Load more, then I want to be loaded second div, if he/she clicks one more time Load more button, I want to be loaded third div (but first two divs shouldn't hide). Is it possible using Javascript or Jquery?

I'm newbie in Javascript. I tried doing using this: http://jsfiddle.net/vendettamit/QB8Hv/ Tried different versions, but I couldn't :(

I don't need to make class hidden and display: none using css. I want this divs not to be loaded, if user doesn't click on button, because I have big traffic.

Comment: I thought if it's possible, to make like that:
        <div id="div1"> some content </div>
        <!---div id="div2"> some content </div->
        <!---div id="div3"> some content </div->
        <!---div id="div4"> some content </div->
        <!---div id="div5"> some content </div->

and onclick remove this comment style for html. There are many pictures in divs and they won't be loaded.

Comment: What's the problem? Your fiddle is working fine for me.

Comment: This fiddle is working fine, but it doesn't do what I need. It loads only one thing every time. How do I make to load other div on next click?

Comment: Either you write the content of the divs dynamicly via javascript or you load the markup / content via AJAX into the page.

Comment: What do you mean "to load other div on next click"? What is the "other" div?

Comment: Load.. It is written already in html but I don't want it to be loaded if user doesn't click load more button. Because there is big traffic on the website and loading big content makes problems

Comment: I mean next div. When user clicks Load more, then it should load second div, if user clicks one more time Load more, then it should load third div...

Comment: You are still not explaining yourself clearly. This is what your fiddle already does.

Comment: Just use `load()` (jQuery function) instead of `document.createElement('div');`.

Comment: It does, but if you click second time, it will load same thing second time. I want to load for example another picture for second click. For third click, I want to load third image ..etc..

Comment: If I understand your predicament, what you need to do is to keep track of the clicks (a click counter) and depending on its value, load the correct content...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly.. you want to load a different image when the user clicks the second time. For that, you need to specify a different image source when the user clicks on it the second time.

There are two ways you could do this. One is to build a JavaScript array that will store the image source paths. When the user clicks on the button successively, take the next element from the array (by using an incremental variable).

For example,

```
var imageSources = [
    "image1.jpg", 
    "image2.jpg", 
    "image3.jpg", 
    "image4.jpg", 
    "image5.jpg", 
]
```

Then when the user clicks on the button,

```
function onClick()
{
     // Get number of image tags already loaded
     var numberOfDivsLoaded = document.getElementById("parentDiv").getElementsByTagName('img').length;

     // Get the next array element
     var nextImageSource = imageSources[numberOfDivsLoaded + 1]

     // Then create an append a new div containing this image to the parent div
}
```

The other way is to use AJAX. When the user clicks on the button, send an AJAX request to load the next image to your back-end script.

Answer (score 1):

Set new class as "hide", and try something like:

```
var showNextElement = function() {
    var elements = $('.hide');
    $(elements[0]).removeClass('hide');
}

$('#btn').addEventListener('click', showNextElement);
```

Comment: Content will be loaded but not displayed. Because of big traffic I want not to load this content if user doesn't click load more.

Comment: you must write somehow, an identifier, how image link. And when you show this div, you calling the application from ajax to show content.

Comment: example: 
    var requestUrl = $(elements[0]).data( "url" );
    $.ajax({
        url: "yourapp.com/public/images/" + requestUrl,
        method: `GET`,
        success: function (data) {
            //insert image inner div, and show
        }
    });